# Express a wave as a sum of cosine

Tags: dft

I started off with this:

$$ x = 5 \cos(200 \times 2 \pi t ) + 10 \cos( 400 \times 2 \pi t)$$

by performing a 1024 point DFT on it. Then I performed IDFT on the complex values obtained through DFT. Now, I want to express the original wave in terms of it's harmonics, so when I combine the DC and first harmonic or upto n harmonics, I get the original wave back. But how do I obtain these harmonics?

This is what I actually want to do. I have some real valued data(144 points). I want to express this data as a sum of cosines. For this purpose, I perform a 144 point DFT operation on this data, and bring them to frequency domain. 
Does the Euler's identity, give me these cosine?

$$X[k] * e^{\tfrac{j2\pi kn}{144}} + X[144−k] * e^{\tfrac{−j2\pi kn}{144}}$$

Please help me obtain the Amplitude and phases of these harmonics.

Comment: Your cosines are both of the same frequency. Are you sure you wrote down the question correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What you want is just the harmonics that represent those two sinusoidal signals? And if I understand correctly, by harmonics you mean the frequency at which each cosine is centered? You want the amplitude and phase of the cosines? I'm not understanding your question :S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate harmonics using DFT from real points](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/calculate-harmonics-using-dft-from-real-points)

Comment: Discrete Cosine Transform?...

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform converts signals into coefficients of cosines *and* sines. This is why the coefficients are complex. Simply adding up those two coefficients won't give you sufficient information about the phase (someone can correct me on this statement, but I believe it's true). In other words, for signal of length *N* you're trying to find coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ such that

$$ x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N/2} a_k \cos(\omega k)+\sum_{k=0}^{N/2} b_k \sin(\omega k)$$

I would suggest using [Discrete Cosine Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) (DCT) instead. It literally breaks you signal up into a sum of cosines, it gives you back all real coefficients and it takes care of the phase problem completely.

If you must use Fourier Transform, you should realize that

$$e^{i \omega t} = \cos (\omega t) + i \sin(\omega t)$$

This tells us that we can recreate the even-symmetric component (cosine) from real coefficients of the Fourier Transform, and odd-symmetric component (sine) from imaginary coefficients of the Fourier Transform.

The formula then befomes:

For a given $k$,

$$a_k \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi kn}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{N}\left( \Re (X[k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi kn}{N}} + \Re (X[N-k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi (N-k)n}{N} } \right), $$

$$b_k \sin\left( \frac{2 \pi kn}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{Ni}\left( \Im (X[k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi kn}{N}} + \Im (X[N-k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi (N-k)n}{N} } \right), $$

where $\Re(\cdot)$ and $\Im(\cdot)$ represent taking real and imaginary part of a complex number respectively. Note that this is done for *each* $n \in \{0 \ldots N-1\}$

Note that because of circular symmetry of DFT, $X[N] = X[0]$, so you'll end up adding up the same thing twice according to the formula above. If you do that, then the *actual* $a_0$ is half of what you get according to the formula above. If you find this division by 2 confusing, [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition) of Wikipedia article on Fourier Series may provide a better explanation (look for the formula where $a_0$ is divided by 2).

Comment: Beware of lots of typographical errors in the statement:
"For each $k$,

$$a_k \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi kn}{N} \right) = \Re (X[k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi kn}{N}} + \Re (X[N-k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi (N-k)n}{N} }, $$

$$b_k \sin\left( \frac{2 \pi kn}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{i}\left( \Im (X[k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi kn}{N}} + \Im (X[N-k]) e^{ \tfrac{i 2 \pi (N-k)n}{N} } \right), $$

where $\Re(\cdot)$ and $\Im(\cdot)$ represent taking real and imaginary part of a complex number respectively. Note that this is done for *each* $n \in \{0 \ldots N-1\}$"

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have to be either blind or wrong in my math. Feel free to fix it or post your own answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate ...or point out what's wrong. Is it the math or the style? I checked the formula with MATLAB. Recovered the signal fine.

Comment: I had voted to close this question as a duplicate of another one which had been answered and the (correct) answer there accepted by OP Rakesh. Your answer is wrong because it does not distinguish $X[0]$ must always be treated separately, and when $N$ is even, as it is in this case, $X[N/2]$ must also be must be treated separately. See [Hilmar's answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1466/235) to the other question or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Trigonometric_interpolation_polynomial).  The result is something that _looks_ like your  (continued)

Comment: $$x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N/2} a_k \cos(\omega k)+\sum_{k=0}^{N/2} b_k \sin(\omega k)$$ which also has typos since the a_0 term is missing. Your assertion that "Note that this is done for each $n \in \{0…N−1\}$" is incorrect; you only need to do it for $1 \leq n \leq (N-1)/2$ and you need to account for $n=0$ and $n=N/2$ (even $N$) separately.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I will fix some of the tings you're talking about, and I agree that it does need a more careful treatment, however I disagree that this is a duplicate. The accepted answer does not show a way of actually expressing a signal as a sum of sines and cosines.

Comment: All right. While you are fixing your answer, be sure to check the formula for $b_k$ carefully; I think you are missing a negative sign there.  In fact, for _both_ $a_k$ and $b_k$, your formulas can be simplified considerably for _real-valued_ sequences $x[n]$ by using $X[N-k] = (X[k])^*$ and Euler's formula.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yeah, I just ran it with Matlab again, and I came up with a better expression for it altogether. Will fix it on the lunch break. = ) Thanks a lot for the feedback.